# Alternatives to locals() for Pyinstaller interactive console

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, interactive

Currently I'm using Pyinstaller to bundle up a large quantity of python scripts I have and place them into an executable.

The main entry point for the executable and in-general running the software uses the

```
import code
... Some functions here ...
def main():
    code.interact(local=locals())
```

This has no problem running when calling it via python -m path.script.py or my entry-point in setup.py, script.

The main problem now is that Pyinstaller does its magic and locals() no longer works as it loses the original values it kept when running the previous way. Now none of my functions are able to be called in the console due to this, previously they were.

Any ideas?

Edit: Pyinstaller command `pyinstaller -F -p src/path/ src/path/script.py`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding a solution that worked with globals().

The key is to have the function main be an entry-point for your script and instead of locals(), swap out for globals().

As for Pyinstaller, the code.interact must be located inside the `__main__` for Pyinstaller to correctly associate all the functions located in script.py.